# How to set default value if Command value is null

Tags: grails

We are using Grails 2.4.3 , In our Command

```
@Validateable
class FreeTextSearchCommand {
    String freeText="*"
    int pageSize=1
    int pageIndex=1
}
```

And in Controller

```
def freeTextSearch(FreeTextSearchCommand freeTextSearchCommand){}
```

So if value comes from Client site is null then I want my default value set , but it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So if value comes from Client site is null then I want my default
>   value set , but it does not work

If you bind null to a property then the result should be null.  That is what the data binder does and it is what the binder is supposed to do.  If you want to impose some custom rules you can do that a number of ways.  One is by using the `BindUsing` annotation.

```
@Validateable
class FreeTextSearchCommand {
    @BindUsing({obj, source ->
        // bind '*' if there is no corresponding request parameter value...
        source['freetext'] ?: '*'
    })
    String freeText

    // etc...
    int pageSize=1
    int pageIndex=1
}
```

See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.3/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding for more details.

I hope that helps.